# Android: Is there a way to validate KASLR at runtime

Tags: android, security, kernel, runtime, aslr

I would like to know if there is a way to check if KASLR is enabled at run time in android target.

I know that ASLR can be validated by checking /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space against value 2(complete randomization for user space apps).

I have configured

```
CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y
```

in the board defconfig file.

Now I want to validate it at run time.

We are using kernel version 4.14 in Android P.

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704640/how-to-detect-in-runtime-is-kaslr-enabled-or-disabled) where it checks the same in ubuntu, with respect to kernel command line args.

I don't see this option in the command line args for android in BoardConfig.mk.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation details of KASLR depend on the CPU architecture (x86, ARM, ARM64, PowerPC, etc.), so I can't say whether you've properly configured it, but at runtime I know of two things you can check:

1. the `/proc/kallsyms` file to see the symbol addresses in virtual memory address space.
2. `lsmod` to see the kernel module addresses in virtual memory address space. **Note:** On some machines, `lsmod` may not show the addresses. In that case, try using `cat /proc/modules` as root. If not using root, the addresses may be all zeros (cleared for security reasons). ~~Thanks to user @crass for the comment!~~

Both 1 & 2 are similar checks, but depending on what's available to you on your system, you might need to use one or the other.

#### 1. /proc/kallsyms

To do so, simply look at the first few lines of `/proc/kallsyms`:

```
root@device:~# head -n 3 /proc/kallsyms
ffffff8008080000 t _head
ffffff8008080000 T _text
ffffff8008080800 T do_undefinstr
```

Note that the address for, e.g., `_head` is `ffff ff80 0808 0000`.

Now reboot your machine and check again.

```
root@device:~# head -n 3 /proc/kallsyms
ffffff9fc8c80000 t _head
ffffff9fc8c80000 T _text
ffffff9fc8c80800 T do_undefinstr
```

Note that the address for, e.g., `_head` is now `ffff ff9f c8c8 0000`.
Compare the high-level bytes and find that `ffffff80080 != 0xffffff9fc8c` so the addresses are being changed across reboots. --> KASLR is enabled.

#### 2. lsmod

Similar to `/proc/kallsyms` method above: check lsmod, reboot, check lsmod again, and compare the addresses.

```
root@device:~# lsmod
iptable_filter 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffa1c49b9000
ip_tables 28672 1 iptable_filter, Live 0xffffffa1c49ad000
```

Note that the address for, e.g., `iptable_filter` is `ffff ffa1 c49b 9000`.

Now reboot your machine and check again.

```
root@device:~# lsmod
iptable_filter 16384 0 - Live 0xffffff2100716000
ip_tables 28672 1 iptable_filter, Live 0xffffff210070a000
```

Note that the address for, e.g., `iptable_filter` is now `ffff ff21 0071 6000`.
Compare the high-level bytes and find that `ffffff2100716 != 0xffffffa1c49b9` so the addresses are being changed across reboots. KASLR is enabled.

You can do these tests iteratively to determine the *quality* of the randomness. How different are the addresses across reboots? Are there obvious patterns? The security benefit of KASLR is proportional to the quality of randomness, or entropy.

References:
[Debugging Linux Kernels with KASLR](https://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/kaslr/)
[Linux Kernel Driver Database for RANDOMIZE_BASE](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RANDOMIZE_BASE.html)